# can some one confirm if this is a thread safe implementation of singleton

Tags: c++, thread-safety, singleton

```
#include "iostream"
#include "atomic"

using namespace std;

class Singleton
{
    Singleton();


    static Singleton * _pInstance;

    public:
       ~Singleton() {
       }

       static Singleton* getInstance() {

          Singleton * tmp = _pInstance;

          atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);

          if (tmp == nullptr){

             tmp = _pInstance;

             if (!tmp) {

                _pInstance = new Singleton();

                atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);

                _pInstance = tmp;
             }

         return _pInstance;
     }
};

Singleton* Singleton::_pInstance = nullptr;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your question?

Comment: I don't know about this one, but it's *trivial* to implement a thread-safe singleton. The simplest singleton, a Meyers' singleton, is already thread safe.

Comment: Dangers of the double checked lock pattern: http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf

Comment: i tryied to add comments to the code but i don't know how to solve this probleme: Please add some context to explain the code sections , i added the atomic_thread_fence is it good with that ?

Comment: @HocineDJEMAI: Can you elaborate on why you're doing this instead of a straightforward thread-safe implementation. Is it research? Homework? What?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation seems to be thread safe, but the simplest way to make a thread safe singleton looks like

```
class Singleton {
    Singleton();

public:
    ~Singleton() {
    }

    static Singleton* getInstance() {
        static Singleton theInstance;
        return &theInstance;
    }
};
```

or better return a reference

```
    static Singleton& getInstance() {
        static Singleton theInstance;
        return theInstance;
    }
```

You don't need to reinvent the wheel here.